# Error building carbon component

Tags: maven-3, wso2

I have been doing http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2014/03/how-to-write-a-wso2-carbon-component/ but when I create client using wsdl file I got this error. How can I solve this issue.

```
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO]                                                                         
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building WSO2 Carbon - Student Manager Stub 4.2.0
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.9.1:add-source (add-source) @ org.wso2.carbon.student.mgt.stub ---
    [INFO] Source directory: /home/jobs/wso2/Carbon/Old/org.wso2.carbon.student.mgt.stub/target/generated-code/src added.
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) @ org.wso2.carbon.student.mgt.stub ---
    [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
    [INFO] Copying 1 resource
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.1:run (source-code-generation) @ org.wso2.carbon.student.mgt.stub ---
    [INFO] Executing tasks
    [java] Retrieving document at 'src/main/resources/StudentManager.wsdl'.
    [java] Dec 05, 2014 1:05:42 AM org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler compile
    [java] WARNING: No schemaLocation for import of http://data.mgt.student.carbon.wso2.org/xsd; compilation may fail
    [INFO] Executed tasks
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) @ org.wso2.carbon.student.mgt.stub ---
    [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
    [WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
    [INFO] Compiling 8 source files to /home/jobs/wso2/Carbon/Old/org.wso2.carbon.student.mgt.stub/target/classes
```

Actually what is this warning means? This where what I cant understand ..

```
[java] WARNING: No schemaLocation for import of http://data.mgt.student.carbon.wso2.org/xsd; compilation may fail
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like domain class has not been updated in ../data/xsd directory in the target code. I suspect that the backend component has been updated and the wsdl has been altered, but the stub has not been updated/created yet. Therefore the client side component doesn't aware of the modifications. I suggest that you may update the wsdl file in stub resources and rebuilding the stub and client should probably solve the issue.

Comment: I managed to create carbon component. But I was getting that warning every time. Don't know what was the problem ?But this is not serious issue unfortunately I understood  it latter (: